# Parameter innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit not available in AWS Aurora 5.7

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-rds-aurora

I'm trying to modify the parameter `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` on a RDS Aurora 5.7 instance from the AWS RDS Web Console and when I look through the parameters in the database I can not find it.

How can I modify this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In Aurora MySQL `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` is a *cluster*-level parameter, you cannot modify it at the instance level. Create a [cluster-level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.CreatingCluster) parameter group to modify this parameter